# How to write a generic object assign|merge function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How would I write the equivalent of {...a,...b} as a generic function in typescript 4.4+.  I know both `a` and `b` are records, but don't know what they are in advance.  I'd like to create a generic type that constrains arbitrary functions to the {...a,...b} operation.

Example that isn't working:

```js
type Rec = Record<string,unknown>
type ExtendRec = <X extends Rec, Y extends X>(x: X) => Y
// or <X extends Rec, Y extends Rec>(x: X) => Y&X
const addA:ExtendRec = <X extends Rec>(x:X) => ({...x, a: 'a'})
const addB:ExtendRec = <X extends Rec>(x:X) => ({...x, b: 'b'})
const addC:ExtendRec = <X extends Rec>(x:X) => ({...x, c: 'c'})
const blank = {} // expected {}
const a = addA(blank) // expected {a:string}, actual:{}
const ab = addB(a) // expected {a:string,b:string}, actual:{}
const abc = addC(ab) // expected {a:string,b:string,c:string}, actual:{}
```

The type error on each of the addA, addB,addC functions is:

```
Type '<X extends Rec>(x: X) => X & { c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ExtendRec'.
  Type 'X & { c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Y'.
    'X & { c: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Y', but 'Y' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, unknown>'.
```

The mystifying thing is that it works if I just remove `ExtendRec` as function annotations, so typescript already has the ability to infer object assign operations correctly, but I can't write a generic function type that constrains an arbitrary function to that extend operation.

Comment: where is `Rec` declared?

Comment: you say `a` and `b` are records but they are assigned strings in your code?

Comment: added Rec.  a, ab, and abc reflect what properties should be on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this type needs a generic (to capture the properties that will be added), as well as the function (to capture the object being extended).

For example:

```
type ExtendRec<R extends Record<string, unknown>> = <X>(x: X) => X & R
```

Now the rest works as you expect:

```
type ExtendRec<R extends Record<string, unknown>> = <X>(x: X) => X & R

const addA: ExtendRec<{ a: string }> = (x) => ({ ...x, a: 'a'})
const addB: ExtendRec<{ b: string }> = (x) => ({ ...x, b: 'b'})
const addC: ExtendRec<{ c: string }> = (x) => ({ ...x, c: 'c'})

const blank = {} // expected {}
const a = addA(blank) // expected {a:string}
const ab = addB(a) // expected {a:string,b:string}
const abc = addC(ab) // expected {a:string,b:string,c:string}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AJgJQgYwDxqhBZFAZyg0wHsAnFbY4KgSyQHMAaKAVyQGskKA7kgB8wqAF4o2ABrCAFHABcUaQEoJY6VABkZALAAoQ5ST0oAQxQoAgsviJU5bAG8Ly+k1ZQAvmMkL1cTE5VwA6cLgOc2UAcnMY71VjClNgCysAITtCRywXKAAjdwZmFh8-KACNSrCIjiKoGIKEpIMTM0sUAGFsh3Q810xizzLfCUq4QODa0MioIcbMFsNk1MKAG3NecedvKAB6ffw4SExEFChd1Y7xzus5As3edUPj0-PL6I9S7yizznM60UVzaKQ6BVumTk5heRwI7wgF2cXxKrDYRW+rF+Fn+gOB3muaXMBUwkO60IKsLeWA+yMUmPYGNR7CGDOx5lxQN2QA)

---

Or maybe this approach that uses a merge function with generics for both arguments. `addA` now just uses that where one argument is the generic and the other is a known type.

```
type MergeFn = <A extends object, B extends object>(a: A, b: B) => A & B
const merge: MergeFn = (a, b) => ({ ...a, ...b })

const addA = <X extends object>(x: X) => merge(x, { a: 'a'})
const addB = <X extends object>(x: X) => merge(x, { b: 'b'})
const addC = <X extends object>(x: X) => merge(x, { c: 'c'})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=2&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCAxAdlAvFAPAQSggA9gI0ATAZygHsAjAKwgGNgAaKAIUJLKtsYtgAPgAUAQwBcUPBzrTOASizCZUAGRcAsAChmNNJWBQAtgmTS4SVBmwS5yzKtEBvKADpP4jp-d0oAL6Kurr6hsbi5OQE2DgAGjykFNT0TKxiRNJxjqpm1qJEHG5SUADk4qVBoQZGUJHk3LEJxEn8qUIZWTmm5hAFRVDyZXSVwXo1EVEAwli4zbzJAmkiBV0qPfmFUG7M0qXMoyHj4YMANuJoANazLgHVJ+Kz9XiidOdXY2G14v7Y9ZwST4TOp0ZhPaYSOiKIA)

This is sort of the same thing as the previous example though. In each case, the added type is declared statically somehow when `addA` is declared, and `X` is inferred at the call time of `addA`.

*Note, I'm using `object` instead of `Record<string, unknown>` because it's shorter, but that's not really too important here.*

Comment: The second one works great since it doesn't require knowing what the exact properties are.   Thanks for that!